# Converting data collected at irregular times into a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have multivariate data collected during the spring and summer seasons (months: 5,6,7,8), not necessarily daily, and over 30 years. How do I turn it into a time series object to conduct a time series analysis?

I have tried:
timeseries <- ts(data, start(2017,5), frequency = 4)

But I didn't know what frequency to have, since it's collected 4 times a year but not as "quarterlies".

This is what the data looks like:

```
    Year  Month Day   ID     Size      Sex      Temperature
    1 2017     5  13  033     54.0       M        13.0
    2 2017     5  15  044     53.5       F        11.0
    3 2017     5  16  141     55.8       M        15.7
```

I figure maybe I will have to add NAs in the data for the months and days that lack collected data. I also don't know how to divide by day AND month per year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Using the data shown in the Note at the end (slightly changed from the question) create a zoo series from Temperature whose times are year + (month-5)/4 reducing multiple values in a month by using `mean` and then convert all that to `ts`.

```
library(zoo)
toYearMon <- function(x) x[[1]] + (x[[2]] - 5)/4
z <- read.zoo(DF[c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Temperature")], index = 1:3, 
  FUN = toYearMon, aggregate = mean)
as.ts(z)
##      Qtr1 Qtr2
## 2017 12.0 15.7
```

`ts` will think the 4 months are quarters but hopefully you can live with that.  Alternately use `z`.

**2)** Another possibility, since there are 123 days from May1st to August31st inclusive, is to create a time variable that is year + 0 for May1st, year + 1/123 for May2nd, ..., year + 122/123 for Aug31st.

```
toDate <- function(x) as.Date(paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], sep = "-"))

sinceMay1 <- function(x) {
  d <- toDate(x)
  may1 <- toDate(data.frame(x[[1]], 5, 1))
  x[[1]] + as.numeric(d - may1) / 123
}

zsm <- read.zoo(DF[c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Temperature")], index = 1:3,
  FUN = sinceMay1)
frequency(zsm) <- 123
```

and now we can use `zsm` or `as.ts(zsm)`

**3)** another possibility if its good enough to use 1, 2, 3, ... for the times is

```
ts(DF$Temperature)
```

**4)** We can create a zoo series like this where toDate is from above:

```
read.zoo(DF[c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Temperature")], index = 1:3,
  FUN = toDate)
```

### Note

We changed the last Month to 6.

```
Lines <- "Year  Month Day   ID     Size      Sex      Temperature
    1 2017     5  13  033     54.0       M        13.0
    2 2017     5  15  044     53.5       F        11.0
    3 2017     6  16  141     55.8       M        15.7"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but do you know of any way without having to coerce the daily data into "quarterlies"? I'm afraid I might lose the trend if I just average the daily data per month...

Comment: I have added more possibilities.  If none of those are what you want you will need to be much more detailed on precisely what  you want.  Note that ts series normally are not used for daily data.

Comment: Can you also convert to "weekly"?

Comment: Replace toYearMon with one that converts to week.